# Laravel Drop Renamed index

Tags: laravel

I created an index with laravel `index()`

```
$table->index(['group_tasks_outline_agreement_uuid'], 'gt_oa_uuid');
```

I have been tried to drop this idex with `dropIndex()`

```
$table->dropIndex(['group_tasks_outline_agreement_uuid']);
or
$table->dropIndex(['gt_oa_uuid']);
```

it shows the error msg : Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP INDEX `hps_purchase_order_hps_purchase_order_uuid_index`; check that it exists

Answer (score 0):

It should be
`$table->index(['group_tasks_outline_agreement_uuid'], 'group_tasks_outline_agreement_gt_oa_uuid_index');`